# Adding an IF Statement to a Filter Method in Vue

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, filter, vuejs2

I am creating an app in Vue that will filter items in a JSON object. I am having issues with adding a checkbox type filter to this app, because I only want the checkbox filter to run if at least one checkbox is checked, and not to run if none are checked. So currently I have:

```
  computed: {
   filteredJobs: function(){
      var filteredList = this.jobs.filter(el=> {
        return el.title.toUpperCase().match(this.search.toUpperCase())
        && el.employmentType.toUpperCase().match(this.selectedJobType.toUpperCase())
        && el.customText12.toUpperCase().match(this.selectedLocation.toUpperCase())
        && el.dateAdded >= this.checkedDate
      });


      if (!this.checkedServiceAreas.length) {
        return filteredList;
      }else{
        return filteredList.filter(job => this.checkedServiceAreas.includes(job.categories.data.map(({name}) => name).join(' ')));
      }

    }

  }
```

So I am doing most of my filtering using select dropdowns, which makes it easy to use the match method to filter the JSON object, but for checkboxes it is a little more difficult because they can be multiple checked. How I currently have it set up is in an IF statement to only filter the checkedServiceAreas if there is at least one checkbox checked. If there isn't just run my normal filtered method.

What I am trying to do is figure out a way to incorporate my IF statement into my filter method without having to do it in two steps like I have above.

Comment: Are you aware of the `:checked` CSS query selector? You can do `document.querySelectorAll(".myInput:checked")` and use that to make a list of all of the check boxes that are checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  return el.title.toUpperCase().match(this.search.toUpperCase())
    && el.employmentType.toUpperCase().match(this.selectedJobType.toUpperCase())
    && el.customText12.toUpperCase().match(this.selectedLocation.toUpperCase())
    && el.dateAdded >= this.checkedDate
    && (this.checkedServiceAreas.length === 0 ||
        this.checkedServiceAreas.includes(el.categories.data.map(({name}) => name).join(' '))));
```